# Android - ImageButton with rounded corners

Tags: android, image, size, rounded-corners

i need to create an ImageButton with an image on android:src and with rounded corners.
How can i do this? I need also to have my custom size for the button and i want the image resize automatically with the button size.

Comment: why not you are using Button with background image ?

Comment: @Sujit how can i do this? I try this : <Button android:background="@drawable/round_button" android:id="@+id/cmdSecco" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="80dip" android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"></Button> round_button is the xml file with shape for rounded corners. I set the background to this xml and then i don't know how to set image to button.

Comment: you can use android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon" to place image above button.

Answer (score 2):

for Round corner ImageButton use it.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle mBundle) {
super.onCreate(mBundle);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

ImageButton image = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img);
Bitmap bitImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.default_profile_image);
image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
image.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerImage(bitImg));
}

public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
    bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

final int color = 0xff424242;
final Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
final float roundPx = 100;

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(color);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

return output;

}
```

Here, roundPx is for round shape. [image: e.g]

Comment: for rectangle background set a transparent background or drawable with states: image_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000")); and set roundPx to 10000 to circle in all sizes.